# Unhide Window using a cell range

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm try to do is Unhide a hidden workbook/window in Excel via VBA but using a cell range on a master sheet.

IF Cell A1 has reference 123456.xlsx   the macro needs to look at Cell A1 and unhide the window named in the cell.  I'm sure it's possible I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It would be great if you provided some code you tried. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Dim myWorkbook As String
myWorkbook = Range("A1").Value
Windows(myWorkbook).Visible = True
```

Comment: I mean a hidden excel workbook.  The workbook opens hidden and I want to be able to unhide the whole workbook to modify then save and close..

Comment: I've got it.. I used the above but changed sheets to workbook and now works a treat..  Thanks for the prompt in the right direction